# Multiple URL Scrape YouTube

Tags: python

I have the script which work for single URL and save it in a file. I want to scrape from multiple url and save into a single file. Help me out.

"""
Main script to scrape the comments of any Youtube video.
Example:
$ python main.py YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
import sys
import time
import pandas as pd

def scrape(url):
"""
Extracts the comments from the Youtube video given by the URL.
Args:
url (str): The URL to the Youtube video
Raises:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
When certain elements to look for cannot be found
"""
url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hDe2kbCI4g&list=PLzivuVVbLcnqDasWGJSCg2euVWlpSf4S0&index=3"

```
# Note: replace argument with absolute path to the driver executable.
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

# Navigates to the URL, maximizes the current window, and
# then suspends execution for (at least) 5 seconds (this
# gives time for the page to load).
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

try:
    # Extract the elements storing the video title and
    # comment section.
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string').text
    comment_section = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="comments"]')
except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    # Note: Youtube may have changed their HTML layouts for
    # videos, so raise an error for sanity sake in case the
    # elements provided cannot be found anymore.
    error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
    error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
    print(error)

# Scroll into view the comment section, then allow some time
# for everything to be loaded as necessary.
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", comment_section)
time.sleep(7)

# Scroll all the way down to the bottom in order to get all the
# elements loaded (since Youtube dynamically loads them).
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down 'til "next load".
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load everything thus far.
    time.sleep(2)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height.
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# One last scroll just in case.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

try:
    # Extract the elements storing the usernames and comments.
    username_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')
    comment_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
    error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
    print(error)

print("> VIDEO TITLE: " + title + "\n")
#print("> USERNAMES & COMMENTS:")

'''for username, comment in zip(username_elems, comment_elems):
    print(username.text + ":")
    print(comment.text + "\n")'''

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Text","Comment"])
for username, comment in zip(username_elems, comment_elems):
    df = df.append({"Text":username.text,"Comment":comment.text},ignore_index=True)
print("> SAVING THE DATA TO CSV FILE:\n")
filename="10-G-3.csv"
df.to_csv(filename) #to save into exisiting csv
print("> SAVE SUCCESSFULLY: " + filename + "\n" )

driver.close()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
scrape(sys.argv[1])